# jQuery UI Datepicker - Return date, arrival and departure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a Booking website (arrival, departure), where I could choose 2 dates (one for arrival and one for deprature) using jQuery UI DatePicker. Once I'd select 2nd date (deprature) I want the program to calculate how many days were there between Arrival and deprature and multiple it *50. once I get that number I'd like to put it in my text form (Price).

So if I give you an example. I'd select "25.05.2021" for my arrival and "28.03.2021" for deprature. So It would return number "3". Then I'd multiple 3*50 so I'd get "150" and put that "150" inside "Price" form.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});

$(function() {
  $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<p>Date 1: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<p>Date 2: <input type="text" id="datepicker1"></p>
<p>Price: <input type="text" id="vrniceno" disabled></p>
```

Comment: Please review the following Demo: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range This should help you do what you want.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't help me that much. I'm trying with JS onChange function right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `onSelect` callback event on the Datepicker object to update the total price.

Also, just add an e.g. `datepicker` class to all your date input fields that you want to convert to jQuery Datepicker objects.

```js
const DAY_IN_MILLIS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

const updateTotal = function() {
  const form = document.forms['booking'];
  const goingRate = form.elements['going-rate'].valueAsNumber; // No parsing needed
  const arrivalDate = $(form.elements['arrival-date']).datepicker('getDate');
  const departureDate = $(form.elements['departure-date']).datepicker('getDate');
  
  if (arrivalDate && departureDate) {
    const days = Math.ceil((departureDate - arrivalDate) / DAY_IN_MILLIS);
    const total = goingRate * days;
    $(form.elements.total).val(total.toFixed(2));
  }
}

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  minDate: new Date(),
  onSelect: function(date, datepicker) {
    updateTotal();
  }
});
```

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 8em 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 0.25em;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

label::after {
  content: ':';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hotel Booking</h1>
<form name="booking">
  <label>Arrival Date</label>
  <input type="text" name="arrival-date" class="datepicker">
  <label>Departure Date</label>
  <input type="text" name="departure-date" class="datepicker">
  <label>Going Rate ($)</label>
  <input type="number" name="going-rate" value="50.00" step="0.01">
  <label>Total ($)</label>
  <input type="number" name="total" step="0.01" disabled>
</form>
```